# Getting the arguments for the bytecode using Javassist

Tags: java, disassembly, javassist, javap

The disassembled code (using javap -c) of http://lpaste.net/338173 looks like this: http://lpaste.net/338175 , on the third column, there is 200 as an argument to "sipush" how can I get this from a class file using javassist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sipush` is a bytecode which takes a single two byte argument which is a number to push onto the operand stack. In Javassist, you can iterate over all bytecode of a method via the `CodeAttribute` that is available from the `CtMethod`'s `MethodInfo`. In your case, it would be the first byte code, but you can check that you reached `Opcode.SIPUSH`. Once you iterated to this instruction you can read the 2 byte argument via the [`s16bitAt`](https://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/html/javassist/bytecode/CodeIterator.html#s16bitAt-int-) method from the iterator. The method takes a zero-based index. In your case, this makes the argument zero for `sipush`, returning `200` as a value.